# Habilitar select ao selecionar com jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

Realizei uma pesquisa superficial sobre habilitar um `select` ao escolher uma opção em outro `select`, mas não encontrei nada que se aplicasse.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select#select1').select(function() {
    $('select#select2').prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <select id="select1">
    <option>Opção 1</option>
    <option>Opção 2</option>
    <option>Opção 3</option>
  </select>

  <select id="select2" disabled>
    <option>Opção 1</option>
    <option>Opção 2</option>
    <option>Opção 3</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Vc tem dois selects, sendo que o primeiro está como Disable, vc quer que ao clicar nele o atributo Disable seja removido é isso?

Comment: Não acredito que todos os eventos são desabilitados.

Comment: @hugocsl Sim! Mas acho que não vai dar certo usando algum evento nele.

Comment: Realmente não sei se é possível, mas vc pode ter um elemento "invisível" por cima do select que quando clicado vc da display:none nele e no select vc tira o disabled.. Mas isso seria gambiarra ao meu ver, deve ter um jeito mais correto pra fazer isso

Comment: Foi exatamente o que eu fiz. Coloquei uma div com background-color: transparent e z-index: 1; sobre ele, e com o jQuery habilitei o select e removi a div com $('div#code').remove(); ao clicar na div. Muita gambi! Obrigado, mais uma vez, @hugocsl.

Comment: @hugocsl Mudei a pergunta para algo mais factível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta usar o `$(...).on("change", ...)`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select#select1').on('change', function() {
    $('select#select2').prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <select id="select1">
    <option>Opção 1</option>
    <option>Opção 2</option>
    <option>Opção 3</option>
  </select>

  <select id="select2" disabled>
    <option>Opção 1</option>
    <option>Opção 2</option>
    <option>Opção 3</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Verdade! Havia me esquecido da função change();. Obrigado!